# 2002 Ford Taurus not cranking

Tags: ford, starting, taurus

My car has no noise when trying to start it so we have tried a new starter it didn't work so my son tried putting a push button on the starter wire it turns over but will not start it seems like its not getting gas but the theft lights is blinking

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a problem with the immobilizer - when starting the car it will "read" the presence of a chip in the key and if for whatever reason it isn't able to detect that chip the immobilizer will prevent the vehicle from starting (which is why even the wired in starter button won't start it)

This could be a problem with either the car or with the key you are using to start it. If you have one try the spare key and see if that makes a difference. If you don't have a spare then you are probably going to have to visit the Ford dealer I'm afraid.

Comment: any shop can program keys on this year Ford. I forget the cutoff date but anything older than 2010(?) can be done with a scan tool.